# Can peewee create a new MySQL database

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I've looked through all the docs I could find, and read the source code...and it doesn't seem you can actually create a MySQL database (or any other kind, that I could find) using peewee.  If so, that means for any the database I may need to connect to, I would need to create it manually using mysql or some other tool.

Is that accurate, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Peewee can create tables but not databases. That's standard for ORMs, as creating databases is very vendor-specific and generally considered a very administrative task. PostgreSQL requires you to connect to a specific database, Oracle muddles the distinction between users and databases, SQLite considers each file to be a database...it's very environment specific.

Answer (score 4):

You can't create a MySQL database with peewee, but you can do it programatically with other libraries, for example with `PyMySQL`.

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='host', user='user', password='password')
conn.cursor().execute('CREATE DATABASE mydb')
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Peewee cannot create databases with MySql or with other systems that require database and user setup, but will create the database with sqlite when the first table is created.